# Is subtraction of inner join from full outer join some type of "join"?

Tags: sql

Given two tables, is there a name for the result of subtracting inner join from  full outer join, both on the same condition? Is it a type of "join"? Thanks.

Comment: it's an `anti-join` which doesn't exist as syntax in SQL (don't know for Relational Theory), must be written using `EXPECT`  or two `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: What information are you trying to extract from the tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a type of `join` in SQL.  You can write it as:

```
select . . .
from a full join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
where a.id is null or b.id is null;
```

If you are looking for `id`s that are in only one table, it can be more efficient to do:

```
select a.id
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id)
union all
select b.id
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id);
```